# Move spritenode in a circle with controls

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, sprite-kit

How would I be able to move a SKSpriteNode along a circle while controlling the movement. For example, there are two buttons, left and right, and each one will make the SKSpriteNode move either clockwise around the circle or counter clockwise.

This is a great example of what I trying to accomplish. Notice how you move 'Trump'.
http://www.trumpsimulator.com/

This is what I have tried so far:

```
let circularMove = SKAction.followPath(circle.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, duration: 5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't move the sprite node at all.

Place the node onto a parent node. (Call it a `layer` or something).

Now rotate the layer.

If you place the sprite off centre then it will follow a circle with a radius of the distance of the sprite from the centre of the layer.

Now you don't need to worry about paths or anything. Just update the rotation angle each update.

Comment: I tried your method. The skspritenode is rotating fine, yet the problem is that it is also rotating around it self, so it is flipping around. How can I make it stay and only the position moves?

Comment: @cooldood just rotate the sprite in the opposite direction. `head.zRotation = -layer.zRotation` or whatever :D